# "mov rbp, rsp" in function prologue

Tags: assembly, x86, callstack, stack-frame

```
push   rbp
mov    rbp, rsp
mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],edi
```

In assembly function prologue, isn't `push rbp` already moves its value to `rsp` ? Why did `mov rbp, rsp` instruction move the same `rsp` values to `rbp` again? Is it necessary or redundant?

Comment: That is not what `push` does.  Read its description again.  It moves the value from `rbp` to the **memory location** which `rsp` points to (after being decremented by 8).

Comment: `push rbp` decrements `rsp` by 8 and then writes the *prior* value of `rbp` to the *memory pointed to by `rsp`*. `mov rbp, rsp` then loads the new `rsp` value into the `rbp` register.

Answer (score 5):

> isn't `push rbp` already moves its value to `rsp`?

No. `push rbp` is equivalent to:

```
sub rsp, 8                 ; but without setting FLAGS
mov [rsp], rbp
```

No more, no less, just like pushing any other register (https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/push).  This stores `rbp` to memory pointed-to by `rsp`,  but doesn't modify registers other than `rsp-=8`. It's not an [`enter` instruction](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/enter).

---

You may already know this, but `rbp` is used as a *frame pointer*. `mov rbp, rsp` saves the previous top of the stack to `rbp`, and this top now serves as the bottom of the current stack frame.

But this creates an issue: if `rbp` has been modified, what about the previous stack frame? Since the stack frame has been modified, after this function returns, `rbp` would be in the wrong position and things would go very wrong.

This is where `push rbp` comes in. It saves the value of `rbp` before being modified so that right before the function returns, `rbp`'s original value can be popped right back to `rbp` so the previous stack frame remains okay.

(Or in other words, `rbp` is call-preserved, so we need to save/restore it as part of setting it up as a frame pointer for our stack frame.)

Answer (score 1):

mov rbp, rsp takes the current value in rsp and moves it into rbp.

Think as:
You want to save the last stackframe and build another one.

There is also a difference between intel (the code above) and at&t syntax.

Intel:
mov dest, source

Comment: These things are all true, but the phrasing of the question makes it clear they do know what `mov rbp, rsp` does.  They're confused about the `push`.